# Construindo DataGrid com C# WPF em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

Tenho um DataTable onde vou armazenar alguns dados que o usuário informa e através dele quero passar as informações para o DataGrid.

```
gvDados.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; //Essa é a ligação entre o DataTable e a Grid
```

No caso o usuário informa o nome da coluna e clica no botão **AdicionarColuna**, que tem o seguinte código:

```
private void btnAddColuna_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    bool valida = true;
    int nroColunas = dt.Columns.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < nroColunas; i++) 
    {
        if (dt.Columns[i].ToString().ToUpperInvariant().Equals(ttbColuna.Text.ToUpperInvariant()))
            valida = false;
    }

    if (valida)
    {
        // gvDados.Columns.Clear();
        DataGridTextColumn c = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c.Header = ttbColuna.Text;

        gvDados.Columns.Add(c);

        cbbColunas.Items.Add(ttbColuna.Text);

        dt.Columns.Add(ttbColuna.Text, typeof(string));
        ttbColuna.Text = "";
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Já existe uma coluna com esse nome","Sistema Comercial |B ",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);    
}
```

Com esse método ele gera as colunas, que eu quero e adiciona a coluna no DataTable e na DataGrid, é correto fazer isso?

Pois se eu colocar apenas no DataTable não é visualizado na DataGrid

Até então está tudo ok, porém quando eu vou adicionar uma linha no DataTable para que ela possa aparecer na DataGrid não dá certo, aparece uma linha porém em branco sem os dados ...

Digamos que o usuario adicionou duas colunas, Tamanho e Cor então meu DataTable teria que receber

```
dt.Rows.Add(ttbTamanho.Text, ttbCor.Text);
```

As informações ficam no DataTable, porém não são exibidas no DataGrid.

Existe algum meio de colocar as informações no DataGrid sem usar o DataTable ou alguma método que faça com que apareça as informações, levando em consideração que as colunas e linhas são adicionadas em tempo de execução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está pedindo pode ser meio complexo. Vou te dar alguns guias e dicas que podem facilitar sua vida.

> Existe algum meio de colocar as informações no DataGrid sem usar o DataTable?

Sim, qualquer objeto que implemente `IEnumerable` pode ser a fonte de dados. Por exemplo: `List<Produto>` ou `ICollection<Categoria>`, inclusive um `List<dynamic>` são fontes válidas.

**AutoGenerateColumns**

A propriedade `AutoGenerateColumns` definida como `true` irá gerar as colunas automaticamente após ter a fonte de dados definida. Se sua fonte de dados for um `List<Pessoa>`, e a `Pessoa` possua os atributos `Nome`, `Telefone` e `Cidade`, será gerado três colunas automaticamente.

**CanUserAddRows**

Com essa propriedade `true`, se você definiu a fonte de dados como um objeto do tipo `List<Pessoa>`, as linhas inseridas na `DataGrid` serão refletidas na coleção (objeto). Note que nessa abordagem, se você adicionar um item na coleção via aplicação(código), essa linha não será refletida na `DataGrid`.

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" />
```

**Code-Behind**

```
private List<Pessoa> pessoas;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pessoas = new List<Pessoa>();
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = pessoas;
 }
```

ou

```
    var listaDinamica = new List<dynamic>
    {
        new { Nome = "José", CPF = "000.000.00-00"},
        new { Nome = "Pedro", CPF = "111.111.11-11"}
    };

    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = listaDinamica;
```

**ObservableCollection**

Acredito que esse seja o melhor tipo de coleção para se trabalhar com DataGrid no WPF. Funciona assim:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Pessoa> pessoas;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pessoas = new ObservableCollection<Pessoa>();
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = pessoas;
     }
```

Usando `ObservableCollection`, se você adicionar uma pessoa na lista via código, irá refletir na `DataGrid`. Se o usuário adicionar uma linha na `DataGrid`, irá refletir no objeto `pessoas`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Obrigado sua resposta foi muito útil e conseguiu me ajudar! se pude me ajudar também nessa agradeço: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183435/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-row-header-de-um-datagrid-atrav%C3%A9s-das-linhas-de-uma-coluna-de-um-da