# Definição de Row Header de um DataGrid através das linhas de uma coluna de um DataTable utilizando C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

Tenho um DataTable com as seguintes informações :

Coluna1 | Coluna2

```
1    |   A
2    |   B
3    |   C
4    |   D
```

Com esse DataTable gostaria de carregar um DataGrid utilizando a primeira coluna do DataTable para ser as Row Header, Ficando assim

```
  A    B   C   D

1

2

3

4
```

Apenas colocar a Coluna2(Na parte superior) eu consegui de um jeito, passando os dados do DataTable1 para o DataTable2 e assim podendo carregar ele para o DataGrid da seguinte maneira:

onde o DtGrade é o DataTable a receber a coluna superior

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dtGrade.Columns.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                    }

                    gvDados.ItemsSource = null;
                    gvDados.ItemsSource = dtGrade.DefaultView;
```

Agora gostaria de adicionar as colunas do lado esquerdo.

Comment: Não entendi. Por favor edite a questão deixando mais claro. Se possível explicar o que quer fazer de verdade, que apenas com ABC, 123, fica meio vago, pelo menos pra mim.

Comment: Murilo, a idéia dessa grade é o seguinte, tenho um sistema de vendas de roupas onde diferentes tamanhos e cores tem valores diferentes, código de barras diferentes ... a ideia de montar essa grade e pra ficar mais evidente a relação de produtos ja cadastrados. Por exemplo tenho uma coluna: tamanho e outra cor ... então varias cores podem ter varios tamanhos, queria fazer essa grade pra que quando clicasse em uma celula que fosse o cruzamento dos itens pudesse visualizar o produto, por exemplo tamanho p, cor preto, tamanho m cor azul ... o que você acha de fazer desse jeito? Estou aberto

Comment: a Sugestões, teria uma melhor forma pra fazer isso?